# Has Nvidia 331.38 support for optimus?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, 14.04

I'm going to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop with Intel & Nvidia graphics card. Do I have to install Bumblebee or Nvidia 331.38 has support for optimus. I don't use Nvidia card I would like to use only Intel card due to lower using battery. THX in advance :-)

Comment: I do have (unfortunately) Optimus technology on my Ntb and I installed 14.04 just yesterday. So far the nvidia card doesn't seem to be working properly, but at least I got some screen through HDMI. Very laggy screen, but at least something since on 13.10 it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Battery saving does work, but I didn't notice any change of performance while using nvidia on internal display. I don't have external display so, I don't know what is the outcome.

Also in graphics details, the nvidia device is detected when on performance mode.

Simple instructions what I followed,

- Open `dash` by tapping <kbd>Super</kbd> (Windows key)
- Search `additional`, click on `Additional drivers`. Following image will open up, **By default `Nouveau` driver will be selected.** Select as shown in picture.

  [image: optimus additional driver]
- Again open dash, search `nvidia`, open `nvidia X server settings`. Choose `intel card` as default. Save and logout. See below picture.

  [image]

Comment: THX a lot. It's what I want. :-)

Comment: After switching to intel and log/out/in; the menu disappeared and I'm unable to recover NVIDIA GPU. 
`sudo prime-select nvidia
Error: alternatives are not set up properly
Error: nvidia mode can't be enabled`

Comment: Hi, I also went ahead and installed 331.38 proprietary, but I cannot switch *TO* Nvidia GPU `GeForce GT 630M`. It says it's using intel card, and when I switch, a dialog box with nothing pops up.